# Многопоточность в c#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Решил проверить мои знания в многопоточности и решить стандартную задачу, благодаря ей. Выбрал задачу, в которой нужно найти количество возможных путей от левой нижней точки к правой верхней, когда можно ходить только вверх или вправо. Начальное решение было такое:

```cs
static void FindPaths (ulong x, ulong y) {
    if (x == width - 1 && y == height - 1) {
        count++;
        return;
    }
    if (x + 1 < width)
        FindPaths (x + 1, y);
    if (y + 1 < height)
        FindPaths (x, y + 1);
}
```

Вызывая FindPaths (0, 0), я получал правильный ответ. И тут я решил воспользоваться многопоточностью и начинать искать пути от клеток в первом столбце и последней строке:
[image: Жёлтые квадраты - это места, с которых начнётся поиск (в новом потоке)]
В конце концов у меня получился такой код:

```cs
static uint width;
static uint height;
static ulong count;
static List<System.Threading.Thread> threads = new List<System.Threading.Thread> ();

static void Main (string[] args) {
    do {
        Console.WriteLine ("Введите количество столбцов:");
    } while (!uint.TryParse (Console.ReadLine (), out width));
    do {
        Console.WriteLine ("Введите количество рядков:");
    } while (!uint.TryParse (Console.ReadLine (), out height));
    for (uint i = 1; i < height; i++) {
        threads.Add (new System.Threading.Thread (() => FindPaths (0, i)));
        threads[(int) i - 1].Start ();
    }
    for (uint i = 1; i < width; i++) {
        threads.Add (new System.Threading.Thread (() => FindPaths (i, 0)));
        threads[(int) i + (int) height - 2].Start ();
    }
    while (threads.Count (x => x.IsAlive) > 0)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (10);
    Console.WriteLine ("Количество путей равно " + count + ".");
    Console.ReadKey ();
}

static void FindPaths (ulong x, ulong y) {
    if (x == width - 1 && y == height - 1) {
        count++;
        return;
    }
    if (y != 0 && x + 1 < width)
        FindPaths (x + 1, y);
    if (x != 0 && y + 1 < height)
        FindPaths (x, y + 1);
}
```

Но ответ выдаёт каждый раз разный и я не могу понять почему. У меня есть предположение, что x и y из разных потоков конфликтуют, но может быть у меня ошибка в коде. Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Стоит отметить, что создание потока - дорогостоящая операция, и вызывать ее для каждого вызова маленькой рекурсивной функции практического смысла не имеет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это происходит из-за замыкания:

```
for (uint i = 1; i < height; i++) {
    threads.Add (new Thread(() => FindPaths (0, i))); // тут
    threads[(int) i - 1].Start ();
}
```

Этот код компилируется примерно в ([тут можете посмотреть полную версию](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)):

```
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass4_0
{
    public uint i;

    internal void <Main>b__0()
    {
        FindPaths(0uL, i);
    }
}

<>c__DisplayClass4_0 <>c__DisplayClass4_ = new <>c__DisplayClass4_0();
<>c__DisplayClass4_.i = 1u;
while (<>c__DisplayClass4_.i < height)
{
    threads.Add(new Thread(new ThreadStart(<>c__DisplayClass4_.<Main>b__0)));
    threads[(int)(<>c__DisplayClass4_.i - 1)].Start();
    <>c__DisplayClass4_.i++;
}
```

Как видете у вас в потоках вызывается один и тот же метод (из одного и того же объекта), т.е. они все используют одну и туже переменную `i`. Исправить это можно, создав промежуточную переменную:

```
for (uint i = 1; i < height; i++) {
    var index = i;
    threads.Add (new System.Threading.Thread (() => FindPaths (0, index)));
    threads[(int) i - 1].Start ();
}
```

Тогда компилятор будет создавать каждый раз новый объект:

```
for (uint num = 1u; num < height; num++)
{
    <>c__DisplayClass4_0 <>c__DisplayClass4_ = new <>c__DisplayClass4_0();
    <>c__DisplayClass4_.index = num;
    threads.Add(new Thread(new ThreadStart(<>c__DisplayClass4_.<Main>b__0)));
    threads[(int)(num - 1)].Start();
}
```

Также у вас все потоки используют одну и туже переменную `count`. Операция `++` не атомарна и не потоко-безопасна. `count = count + 1` тут идет одновременно чтение и запись и в теории, может произойти чтение старых данных (т.е. два потока прочитали 2 и оба же потока потом увеличили на 1 и записала 3). Лучше использовать [Interlocked.Increment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Interlocked_Increment_System_Int64__).

P.S. Вы каждый раз создаете новый поток, это достаточно "тяжелая" операция, возможно вам будет хватать потоков из ThreadPool.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь всё работает. Но я не очень понимаю, почему проблема в i. Если я в цикле буду просто вызывать метод с параметрами (0, i), то там же всё будет хорошо. Или проблема в том, что пока поток запустится, то переменная уже может измениться и в поток попадёт уже новое значение?

Comment: @DanBear да, т.к. все потоки используют тот же объект, то когда вызывается метод, может произойти, что они будут стартовать с одинаковыми данными

Comment: `Или проблема в том, что пока поток запустится, то переменная уже может измениться и в поток попадёт уже новое значение?` да. При захвате переменной вы по сути захватываете ссылку на нее.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, а как тут использовать ThreadPool, разве он не запускает методы тогда, когда основной поток "спит"?

Comment: @DanBear нет, это коллекция которая уже содержит некоторое количество созданных потоков, на который выполняется ваши задачи, т.е. потоки не будут создаваться, а переиспользоваться, а т.к. у вас задачи не долгие, то создавать много потоков и сразу же их выбрасывать не выгодно (долго создавать/освобождать + ещё время на переключение между потокоми, если их больше, чем потоков на процессоре)

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, просто я видел примеры с ThreadPool, где основной поток на секунду или 3 останавливали. И было написано, что если убрать Thread.Sleep, то сначала бы весь поток закончил работу, а потом уже запустился метод в ThreadPool. Но если всё таки это работает не так, то мне всё равно нужно будет приостанавливать основной поток, что бы вывести ответ после прохождения всех потоков. Но как я могу проверять, сколько потоков заняты мною в ThreadPool? Видел там GetMaxThreads и GetAvaliableThreads, но там вроде нет количества занятых потоков.